# Signal-Slot for TabbedPane Blackberry 10

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry, blackberry-10

I'm a newbie to Blackberry 10 development and the whole qt signal-slot mechanism.
I am trying to register a signal and slot for when a user clicks on a different tab in my Blackberry 10 native application. I have the following code for my UI:

```
TabbedPane {
    id: mainTabbedPane
    showTabsOnActionBar: true
    peekEnabled: true
    sidebarState: SidebarState.VisibleFull
    Tab { 
        ...
    } //End of first tab
    Tab { 
        ...
    } //End of second tab
    ...
```

**applicationui.cpp**

```
AbstractPane *appPane = qmlDocument->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();

    if (appPane) {
        // Set the main application scene to NavigationPane.
        Application::instance()->setScene(appPane);
    }

    TabbedPane* tabbedPane = appPane->findChild<TabbedPane*>("mainTabbedPane");
    qDebug("Pane: %p", tabbedPane);

    QObject::connect(tabbedPane, SIGNAL(activeTabChanged(bb::cascades::Tab*)), SLOT(sectionTriggered(bb::cascades::Tab*)));
```

My issue is that it seems the TabbedPane is not being found despite being in the UI.  What I'm I doing wrong? Also, I'm I implementing the signal-slot correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use onTriggered in QML, so you can get that this way. Depends on what you want

```
Tab {
     title: "Tab name"
     onTriggered: {

     }
 },
```

BUT to fix your problem directly, you're missing objectName

```
TabbedPane {
    id: mainTabbedPane
    objectName: "mainTabbedPane"
    showTabsOnActionBar: true
    peekEnabled: true
    sidebarState: SidebarState.VisibleFull
    Tab { 
        ...
    } //End of first tab
    Tab { 
        ...
    } //End of second tab
```